# Inner spacing inside rounded checkbox

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to achieve this: 
[image]

I've also managed to get the result, but I cannot add the spacing between the grey border and blue circle:

```
input {
  line-height: normal;
  &[type="checkbox"],
  &[type="radio"] {
    width: 1.3em;
    height: 1.3em;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 50%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-width: thick;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Add a third circle with the background color as the fill color?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `border: 2px solid white;` for the white ring, and `box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #ddd;` for the outer grey ring.

Then you can set `background-color` to `white` for unchecked or `#73c0ec` for checked.

```css
input[type="radio"] {
  width: 1.3em;
  height: 1.3em;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid white;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #ddd;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked {
  background-color: #73c0ec;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="group-1"><br>
<input type="radio" name="group-1"><br>
<input type="radio" name="group-1">
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for custom radio style like this

```css
 .radio-custom {
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;   
}

 .radio-custom, .radio-custom-label {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.radio-custom-label {
    position: relative;
}

.radio-custom + .radio-custom-label:before {
    content: '';
    background: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #ddd;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 2px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}


.radio-custom + .radio-custom-label:before {
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.radio-custom:checked + .radio-custom-label:before {
    background: #ccc;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 4px #fff;
}


.radio-custom:focus + .radio-custom-label {
  outline: 1px solid #ddd; /* focus style */
}
```

```html
    <form>
        <h2>Radio Buttons</h2>
        <div>
            <input id="radio-1" class="radio-custom" name="radio-group" type="radio" checked>
            <label for="radio-1" class="radio-custom-label">First Choice</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input id="radio-2" class="radio-custom"name="radio-group" type="radio">
            <label for="radio-2" class="radio-custom-label">Second Choice</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input id="radio-3" class="radio-custom" name="radio-group" type="radio">
            <label for="radio-3" class="radio-custom-label">Third Choice</label>
        </div>
    </form>
```